# Is there a Mendeley Plugin for LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex

I am looking for a plugin for Mendeley that easily integrates LaTeX

Comment: What type of integration, besides to export automatically to BibTeX and the "Copy As LaTeX Citation Command" (Ctrl-K) are you searching for?